# Is List<string> guaranteed to be in correct order when serialized to JSON?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, list

Is there any condition where the serialized JSON array is not in the same order as the .NET List that was originally serialized?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET if yes then which versiion ? Show us the code that serializes your object to json. In my projects, the items of a list always appear in the same order once serialized as json. Never had any problems with this.

Comment: Yes, it's ASP.NET 4.5 and the List<string> list is being returned as a anonymous object like new { list } for JS to process in client-side

Comment: That depends *entirely* on the JSON library you are using. So without knowing that, the answer is 'maybe'.

Comment: What if I used the default serializer then for dynamic object in .NET? I did not specify a serializer and just passed a dynamic object.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic object"  you mean this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx ?? Anyways if your controller is returning json like this: return Json(object). Then yes, your items will always be serialized in order.

Comment: I wouldn't depend on the inner workings of the serializer anyway. Imagine what would happen when the inner workings changes in a future version of the serializer?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using JSON.NET and default JSON Serializer settings, your list will be serialized to a JavaScript  array of strings in the same order as per the JSONConvert.SerializeObject() method code found here.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs